# Output varibale is not scalar. Matlab. HDL Coder

Tags: matlab, http-live-streaming, hdl-coder

I've folowing main function (listing 1), that have to be converted to HDL.

Listing 1 – HDLCoder.m:

```matlab
function [out] = HDLCoder(a,b)
out = fir1(48,[a b]);   % Window-based FIR filter design
end
```

Also, I've folowing testbench function, that need to verifying of main function (without this function I cannot generate HDL):

Listing 2 – Calculator.m

```matlab
[out] = HDLCoder(0.35,0.65);
```

So, I've folowing "Workspace" and "Workflow Advisor" setting, output of compilation as well.

[image]
Picture 1 – Workspace window

[image]
Picture 2 – "Workflow Advisor" in "HDL Workflow Advisor" tab

[image]
Picture 3 – "Workflow Advisor" in "Desine Input Types" tab

In "Workflow Advisor" in "Fixed-Point Conversion" tab I've folowing error (picture 4):

> Variable 'out' is not scalar. Non-scalar types are not supported for derived range analysis.

[image]
Picture 4 – "Workflow Advisor" in "Fixed-Point Conversion" tab

[image]
Picture 5 – "Workflow Advisor" –> "Fixed-Point Conversion" -> "Variable" tab

[image]
Picture 7 – "Workflow Advisor" –> "Fixed-Point Conversion" -> "Output" tab

[image]
Picture 8 – Compiler's window with underling place with error

I already was trying to delete brackets around "out" varible in different places. It's not changed error output.

Comment: In this case, `fir1` produces 49 numbers, the system you’re using expects a single output number. I don’t know what this “derived range analysis” is, and why you need to use that with this code. So I can’t help you fix this. But the error message is clear, and it has nothing to do with the square brackets.